# Find the active Excel Table

Tags: office-js

Say, there are number of tables created with `ctx.workbook.tables.add(..)`

Is there a way to know which table the user is currently on?

These tables differ in structure, content, etc. and we want to show specific actions/UIs on the task pane.
Only way I can see is to iterate through the tables collection, looking up all their range boundaries and see if the active table is within one of those tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:  See the answer at [Find table intersect with selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729658/find-table-intersect-with-selection).**

The functionality is on the backlog, but hasn't been implemented yet. You could get `ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange()` for current selection (as a Range object), but with tables you'd need to loop through each and gets its range -- loading rowIndex, columnIndex, rowCount, columnCount -- and compare against the properties of the selected range.  So possible, but not currently easy.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: UPDATE: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729658/find-table-intersect-with-selection