# How to get the current active table using Excel Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-js

In an Excel Add-in that uses Javascript API, I'm trying to get the active table where the cursor is currently at.  After that I'd like to get the range object (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range) of the table and perform a number of useful tasks like locking/unlocking specific cells, etc.  I can get the current active sheet and selected range, but I can't find any API or API combinations that can get the active table.

I tried the shared API Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync().  It can get a TableBinding of the active table, but the TableBinding is a generic shared one (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.tablebinding) instead of the Excel specific one (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/binding).  As a result, I can't get the range object and perform a number of useful operations using the range object.

Could anyone share some ideas how to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: You can definitely write a method to do this, but you need to further define your behavior.  What happens if you have two distinct tables selected?  Do you want to return an array of all active tables?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735631/678505

Comment: Thanks!  It solved my problem.  It's just that this can be done with a single ExcelApi1.1 call Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync.  After advancing to ExcelApi1.3+, we have to write a function to do this. :(